# Modificar variables de entorno globales

Tags: python, windows, environment

Estoy haciendo un instalador, por lo cual al finalizar deseo agregar en el PATH de mi sistema operativo (Windows) una variable de entorno referente a mi programa. Para ello intente (ciegamente) con el módulo `os` haciendo:

```py
import os

PATH = os.environ["PATH"]
PATH += "C:\mi_program.exe;"
```

Y claramente esto funciona pero solo durante la ejecución del programa ya que `os.environ` crea una "copia" de las variables de entorno al momento de ejecutar el programa y en nuestro programa se trabaja con esta "copia", por eso el PATH ha quedado intacto en todo momento.

Entonces, ¿Cómo puedo modificar las variables de entorno de forma permanente?

Comment: Segun [las respuestas de una pregunta del sitio en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716011/why-cant-environmental-variables-set-in-python-persist) no es posible con Python, pero si con comandos de shell.

Comment: PD: en los comentarios ofrecen otras dos preguntas relacionadas. Espero aunque sea poder ayudar un poco.

Comment: Christian, tu pregunta está a un voto de ser cerrada. Supongo que la comunidad espera que pongas en la pregunta tus intentos de lograr el objetivo. Sinceramente, no estoy de acuerdo, tu pregunta está perfecta desde mi punto de vista.

Comment: En primer lugar, gracias por el link brindado. En segundo lugar, no sé que mas debo de poner, el codigo que muestro es lobque intenté y es el código mínimo para replicar el problema

Comment: De nada c: Yo creo que lo que se espera es que pongas links de las paginas que visitaste.

Comment: Si no he encontrado nada, lo único que me aparece es sobre modificar las variables de entorno con `os.environ` (tal vez soy malo buscando). No soy como las personas que si tienen una duda viene y preguntan sin buscar nada nada

Comment: Yo confio en que no eres de los que no investigan, pero igualmente es necesario demostrarlo. Yo siempre busco en ingles, aunque tenga que usar el traductor de Google. Ojala mi consejo te sirva. Aun asi, no tengo idea si eres malo buscando o si simplemente no hay muchas paginas que hablen del tema.